# Variable Definition not global accessible due webpack?

Tags: javascript, webpack

I have a legacy JavaScript file which define a global variable like in the following example.

```
var core_functions = function () { }
```

I'm using webpack to bundle/build all my assets... after that the browser throws an error that core_functions is not defined. How can I fix this error and tell webpack that this variable definition should be global (And yes, I know that this is not the best way).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your script:

```
global.core_functions = core_functions;
```

Comment: Okay, this way is possible, yes :) Thanks!